# Word Find - find any highlighted text that starts with a squared bracket

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find

Is there a way to Find highlighted text that ONLY begins with a open square bracket? I've tried using the square bracket as a wildcard, but it won't find any adjoining words.

For example, I have a document containing conditional paragraphs, in squared brackets, with the "name" of the paragraph highlighted at the beginning:

"**[Document** to return Thank you for sending the documents requested earlier.]"

(the section in bold is highlighted in blue in Word)

Is there a way to find "**[Document to return**"?

I hope this makes sense

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do this in one go without code, or find highlighted text of a particular colour (i.e. blue), but one way would be to use a wildcard search looking for highlighted text and using a pattern such as this to find entries with 4 words (but possibly not space after the last word)

```
\[<[! ]{1,100}> <[! ]{1,100}> <[! ]{1,100}> <[! ]{1,100}>
```

Then reduce that to find stuff with just 3 words

```
\[<[! ]{1,100}> <[! ]{1,100}> <[! ]{1,100}>
```

and so on...

You would hope that things like

```
\[<[! ]{1,100}>( <[! ]{1,100}>){2}
```

would work and make things easier, but it doesn't appear to.